# Best practice designing a permission system

Tags: python, sql, permissions, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm currently developing a little Python website using Pyramid.
But I don't know how to design the permission system.
The System should be very flexible: I have to establish connections between many different tables.
Instead of writing one permission table for every variant i thought to just create one table - I call it PermissionCollection:

PermissionCollection:

- permissionCollectionId - PrimaryKey
- onType = ENUM("USER","TEACHER","GROUP","COURSE"...)
- onId = Integer

and the Permission table:

- permissionId - PrimaryKey
- key
- value
- permissionCollectionId - ForeignKey

I'll define standard PermissionCollections for every possible relationship hard-coded in sources and if a user,course,teacher... has special rights i'll create a new PermissionCollection and add the permission to it.

I'm very new to web programming, and don't know if this approach is useful. Or if something like this even exists. I think the Pyramid ACL isn't the right tool for this task, is it?

Comment: Most RDBMSs have a `GRANT`/`REVOKE` command which is used to allow access (At various levels) to tables/schemas in the database.  Some of them even have the concept of user-groups, too, which means that you can do the command for the entire group.  So you could be attempting to do something at the application level, which is already present at the database level (which would be much more secure).

Comment: But isn't GRANT for the users of my database? And user of my app doesn't mean database user

Comment: `GRANT` _is_ for database users, yes.  But if you wrote your app to check permissions (based on who/what logged into the app), you may as well log them in as a specific database user, too (you can supply these in the connection string, usually).  Which would help with auditing, as well as controlling access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you read about it already but pyramid does come with a really nice permission system. Authorization with ACL.

How to handle it, it really only depend of you...
You could have a ACL table

(object_id, allow/deny, who?(group, userid), permission, order)

- object_id is a unique id to a record in your database
- allow/deny is what this ACE is supposed to do...allow or deny access
- who? is either a group, username or whatever you want for example system.everyone is everyone
- permission is the permission parameter in view_config
- order is one important thing order does matter

For example

```
__acl__ = [
(Deny, Everyone, 'view'),
(Allow, 'group:admin', 'view')
]
```

This sample will always deny view even for admin... As soon as pyramid find something that tells you if you can see or not see a record it automatically stop searching

```
__acl__ = [
(Allow, 'group:admin', 'view'),
(Deny, Everyone, 'view')
]
```

This will allow view for every admin but not for anyone else. That is why you have to remember the order of your ACEs.

The fun part is here actually. This is all good. You have acl mapped to a record in your data. When you load for example a page... You will have to load the acl and set them in your object.

```
myobject.__acl__ = load_acls(myobject)
```

If you have a data tree. You can even not set acls.

For example you have a site that looks like that

> ```
> root
>   \--pages with acl
>       +---- page1  without acl
>       \---- page2  with acl
> ```

When you will access page1, it will check for **acl** if it can't find it, it will check for **parent** if **parent** has an acl, it will check permission for it, if it doesn't it will check for its **parent** until you reach root. If it can't find the permission, im not so sure what happens.. I guess it will either give you a forbidden error or predicate error. That it can't find the proper view.

That said, in order to make that work you have to make location aware object that knows their parents.

But why would you want to do all that?

You can have acl for any object and have really fine grained control on who can watch or not every object in your database. You can also put acl directly in your class object without database.

as long as your acl is in the attribute **acl** pyramid will be able to do something with it. It's not really important how you got it.

Check this out

http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/wiki/authorization.html

Comment: Nice. thank you. And i could also use my table? In your approach: how can the application figure out if who:1 stands for user with id 1 one group with id 1? So, I just write a function that generates this acl tuple for every element in the traversal tree. Can i just load the acl in the contructor?

Comment: yeah you can load the acl anywhere as long as your instance as the __acl__ set to a list of tuple (ACE).

Comment: the order is really important. As soon as pyramid find out if it can allow or deny access to an element. It will return. In some case order won't really matter if you have simple permissions. But my example above... if you deny everyone first and then allow only admin in second... It will deny everyone then return. It won't even check allow admins. So setting an order is really important if you want to control which ACE comes first in the ACL. Also, if you go in the development.ini file. You can enable auth debug